# C++ vector exception handling: Which one is the better way of throwing out_of_range() and why?

Tags: c++, exception, std, stdvector

I would like to know which of the following ways of throwing a user-defined exception upon `out_of_range()` error would be a better way of doing it. To me, as someone not so experienced, they are identical. But I got curious to know if there would be any difference between the two and if so, what.

```
std::vector<int> container {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int function1(int x, int y) {

    if(x < 0 || y < 0)
        throw USER_DEFINED_OUT_OF_RANGE();

    if(x >= container.size() || y >= container.size())
        throw USER_DEFINED_OUT_OF_RANGE();

    return container[x] + container[y];

}

int function2(int x, int y) {

    try {
        return container[x] + container[y];
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& e) {
        throw USER_DEFINED_OUT_OF_RANGE();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one works, and the second one doesn't. So the first one is better.

(`container[x]` is undefined behaviour if `x` is out of range, it doesn't throw. You could fix that by using `at()`, as @NeilButterworth suggests.)

But you're missing a bigger point - you shouldn't be doing this at all. There's a perfectly good standard exception for this context, converting it to something else isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I might want to have separate exceptions to replace `std::out_of_range` with is that, say I'm setting or getting values of two separate containers in the same function, say `function1()`, and those two containers might have special meanings in an application (maybe it is a math application and which container is which matters), so I might want to throw `CONTAINER_1_OUT_OF_RANGE()` or `CONTAINER_2_OUT_OF_RANGE()`. Does this sound impractical or unnecessary?

Comment: I've not seen situations where that level of detail in the exception type was useful (although obviously that doesn't mean there are none). It would be much better to not access out of range elements; if you do it's a bug, and the exception message and stacktrace are likely to be more useful than the type. Exceptions should be exceptional; catching them and then making decisions based upon their details doesn't feel like the right way of doing things to me.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors already throw exceptions if indexes are out of range. Use:

```
   container.at(x) + container.at(y)
```

or alternatively say in your documentation that the result of using invalid indexes is undefined, and don't do any checking at all.

Comment: But what if I want to `throw USER_DEFINED_OUT_OF_RANGE();` instead?